# PHP. Проверка статуса пользователя

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Такая проблема: в бд таблице есть строка `status` в неё могу записывать `banned` и `active` соответсвенно.
Нужно чтобы на главной странице `(php-файл)` выводилась информация для каждого типа отидельно: тоесть для забаненого `echo '<h1>Извините вы забанены</h1>';` и для активированного  `echo '//содержание скрипта';` Как это сделать с помощью переменной`$status`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую использовать другой подход.

поле status с типом tinyint и длина значения 1, по умолчанию 0

0 будет означать что пользователь активен, если изменить значение на 1 в таком случае пользователь забанен и тогда код будет такой:

```
if ($status) {
    echo "<h1>Извините вы забанены</h1>";
} else {
    echo "<h1>Ваш аккаунт активен</h1>";
}
```

Comment: Вопрос: Какой должна быть строка? varchar?

Comment: поправил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо но мне подошел первый вариант, где if ($user['status'] == "admin") {<a href="">ADMINPANEL</a>} else {}